# Make generalize CRUD operations in sqlite for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I want to make crud operation operattions in my application. I have 50 tables. I want to apply insert, update, delete on all tables. So Can I make all 4 operations for each table or I make a generaliza 4 functions that will perform CRUD.

for example I doing in this way for

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
{
     foreach (var item in temp.Result.StaticTable)
     {
         db.Insert(new StaticTable()
         {
               siStaticTableID = item.siStaticTableID,
               vcTableName = item.vcTableName,
               dtUpdTime = item.dtUpdTime
         });
     }

     db.Commit();
     db.Dispose();
     db.Close();
     var line = new MessageDialog("Records Inserted");
     await line.ShowAsync();
```

This is only for a single table now I want to perform this for all tables how can I do that Need help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this example about a generic repository using entity framework.

try to implement something like this

Your base model

```
class BaseModel {
    //TO ensure all your models have and id
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Your model in facts

```
class Customer :BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Base Crud

```
class BaseCrud<T> where T : BaseModel {

    //initialice your db 
    protected SQLite.SQLiteConnection db;

    public bool Delete(T item) {
        return db.Delete<T>(item.Id) > 0;
    }

    public bool Update(T item) {
        return db.Update(item) > 0;
    }

    public bool Insert(T item) {
        return db.Insert(item) > 0;
    }
}
```

An specific crud in case you need to do some special thing on your model

```
class CustomerCrud : BaseCrud<Customer> {
    public List<Customer> GetAll() {
        return db.Table<Customer>().ToList();
    }
}
```

[Generic repository Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte)

[And this another tutorial about SQLite](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx)

Also take a look at [repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).